# Algebra (Math Test 1)

Tags: linear-algebra

Tom is 150 cm tall. Dick is x cm taller than Tom. Harry is 4 cm taller than Dick. How much taller is Harry than Tom in terms of x?

Answer (score 1):

Let $T,D,H$ be the heights of Tom, Dick and Harry respectively.

Then you are given that $T=150$, $D=T+x$ and $H=D+4$.

Substitute in for $D$ to get $H=T+x+4$. In other words, Harry is $(x+4)$cm taller than Tom.